# How do I add multiple different cookies in a url with requests?

Tags: python, cookies, python-requests

I've been trying to post 2 different types of cookies but the error code I get is:

```
  b = requests.post("https://www.rolimons.com/tradeapi/create", cookies=RolimonsCookieAdd, cookies=RolimonsRobloxAdd)
                                                                                             ^
SyntaxError: keyword argument repeated
```

And my code is:

```
RolimonsCookieAdd = {'RoliVerification': 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoxLCJwbGF5ZXJfZGF0YSI6eyJuYW1lIjoiNzZfNzciLCJpZCI6MTUxMjExNDM0fSwiaWF0IjoxNTk4MTcwMjE5LCJleHAiOjE2MDU5NDYyNzl9.Wd5wKOdjQqwHUxYPDJtacw_JYzu4cRpel6V4Q0MCrkc'}
RolimonsRobloxAdd = {'ROBLOSECURITY': '_|WARNING:-DO-NOT-SHARE-THIS.--Sharing-this-will-allow-someone-to-log-in-as-you-and-to-steal-your-ROBUX-and-items.|_CD34AEC12CDF5DD8D40320A1C94FEAC6E9E706D42B0B6FC7BFF1D2452239B38206E3'}

b = requests.post("https://www.rolimons.com/tradeapi/create", cookies=RolimonsCookieAdd, cookies=RolimonsRobloxAdd)
print(b.json())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary:

```
mycookies = {'RoliVerification': 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoxLCJwbGF5ZXJfZGF0YSI6eyJuYW1lIjoiNzZfNzciLCJpZCI6MTUxMjExNDM0fSwiaWF0IjoxNTk4MTcwMjE5LCJleHAiOjE2MDU5NDYyNzl9.Wd5wKOdjQqwHUxYPDJtacw_JYzu4cRpel6V4Q0MCrkc',
                 'ROBLOSECURITY': '_|WARNING:-DO-NOT-SHARE-THIS.--Sharing-this-will-allow-someone-to-log-in-as-you-and-to-steal-your-ROBUX-and-items.|_CD34AEC12CDF5DD8D40320A1C94FEAC6E9E706D42B0B6FC7BFF1D2452239B38206E3'}
b = requests.post("https://www.rolimons.com/tradeapi/create", cookies=mycookies)
print(b.json())
```